# Getting undefined result on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call my controller by jquery ajax.My controller action method.My ajax is runnig successfully and my method is being called but it responses with a undefined result.Can anyone help me out with this
My Ajax Code is

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function(res) {
    alert(res.d);
  },
  error: function(res) {
    alert(res.status);
  }
})
```

it calls to a student controller which have a action method named create which is defined as below
[HttpPost]

```
public JsonResult Create(string name)
    {
        return Json(name,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write your method as this way. Now you are returning in success fucntion
only **res.d** object (but res.d not exists), rather than you should write **res.name** because you are returning **name** from Json method.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function(res) {
    alert(res.name);
  },
  error: function(res) {
    alert(res.status);
  }
})
```